# Why this code is showing TLE for following constraints 1≤T≤10 1≤K≤N≤10^6

Tags: c++, string, time

Why this code is showing TLE in the time limit of 1 sec ?
taking string inputs to be of size 10^6 and 10 in number
total number of operation touch approax 10^8 ,which is inclusive in the range of 1 sec but this code shows TLE;
Question : To find a substring of particular length and particular character in a main string
ex:
Example Input
3
5 2
*a*b*
5 2
*a**b
5 1
abcde

Example Output
NO
YES
NO

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include<string>
 using namespace std;

 int main() {
    int t;
    cin>>t;
    while(t--)
    {
        int n;
        cin>>n;
        int k;
        cin>>k;
        string s ;
        cin>>s;
        string a="";
        string r(k,'*');
       // cout<<r<<endl;
       string ans = "NO";
        for(int i = 0 ; i <= n-k;i++)
        {
            a = s.substr(i,k);
            if(a==r)
            {
                ans ="YES";
                break;
            }
        }
        cout<<ans<<"\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `substr` hides plenty of memory allocations and string copies. Memory allocation in particular is not cheap.

Comment: What is that code supposed to do? It looks like you could just do `std::cout << s.find(r) == string::npos ? "NO" : "YES";`.

Comment: Yes it is doing the exact functionality of "find" function but exceeds time limit with given constraints

Comment: It's exceeding the time limit because of all the memory allocations and copying.

Comment: Can you suggest an edit?

Comment: Sure: use `find` instead of replicating it badly.

Comment: I tried it ,still it is exceeding time limit

Comment: Then I suspect that the problem is not as you described it. (Your example says pretty much nothing.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because time complexity of substr is O(N), N being the length of the substring. So in the worst case, your code will run in O(N^2) which is not accepted if N >= 10^4

Additional:
O(N) will be accepted if N <= 10^7 while some online platforms allow it up to 10^8